# Do we need to define target table in HBase shell before loading reduce() output into it?

Tags: hbase

I have HBase installed but have not created any tables to load the data. Now, do we need to explicity create the table and mention the column names in HBase shell or can we do it in the MapReduce program, if we want to load the output of reduce() into an HBase table?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the table in advance. Create it either from the shell or add the code to create the table in your job itself. This is how it can be done through code:

```
HBaseConfiguration conf = HBaseConfiguration.get(); 
HBaseAdmin hbase = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
HTableDescriptor desc = new HTableDescriptor("TEST");
HColumnDescriptor meta = new HColumnDescriptor("cf".getBytes());
desc.addFamily(meta);
hbase.createTable(desc);
```

You don't need to specify the columns while creating a table, but column family is mandatory. Column names can be added at the time of putting the data.

The difference between columns in a RDBMS and column families in HBase is that a column is just `a set of data values of a particular simple type, one for each row of the table`, while a column family defines a lot more, such as `compression, number of versions to maintain, time to live, maximum and minimum number of versions` etc.

At its core a column family is nothing but a collection of similar columns. This helps in building semantical or topical boundaries between the data.

When you say that you need 2 columns in your table you could either have both these columns in a single family or both in 2 different families. But having lesser number of families is advisable, so you should go with just 1 family.

```
hbase(main):004:0> create 'demo', 'cf'
```

Now you need 2 columns in this table :

```
hbase(main):006:0> put 'demo', 'row1', 'cf:fld1', 'value1'

hbase(main):006:0> put 'demo', 'row1', 'cf:fld2', 'value2'
```

See how columns are specified dynamically at the time of Put. Also, note that family is just `cf` and not `cf:fld1` or `cf:fld2`. The colon character (:) delimits the column family from the column name and together they are called as `column qualifier`.

HTH

Comment: You are welcome. The best online resource would be the official website : hbase.apache.org...Why do you want to use the old API? The new one cleaner and better.

Comment: Can I have the reason for downvote? Trust me I don't give a damn about my reputation, but I deserve an explanation.